# Ansi C: Attempting to count total chars in a file

Tags: c, arrays, file-io

The task is simple but I am having an issue with the method returning 0.

This means my loop:

```
int getCharCount(FILE *fp) {
    int c;
    int i = 0;
    while( (c = fgetc(fp)) != EOF)  {
        i++;
        printf("Loop ran");
    }
    return i;
}
```

Did not run.

In my testing I found that the loop never runs because the "Loop ran" never prints. I am new to c and not sure if I am doing something wrong when trying to count chars in the file.

I feel like I should mention that the file is opened with "wb+" mode and that there are a few long methods that edit the file. Essentially before using this getCharCount() method the text file is cleared of all previous data, then user enters a number of 44 char length strings at a time and I use this method I just posted to calculate the total number of chars which will be used to navigate my display data method.

I am in a library working on this so if anything extra is needed to be posted or if anything needs to be clarified I will try to be quick with my responses. I don't want to post my whole code because there would be a chance to cheat and I need to get this done myself.

Thanks ahead.

Comment: Add a `fflush(stdout)` after your `printf` call and see if it changes something.

Comment: You probably didn't seek to the beginning after writing.

Comment: tried fflush(stdout); sadly that didn't help I will now try to seek. How would one correctly point the seek to the beginning of the file?

Comment: BTW, ANSI C is very old (it is C89). Please upgrade your standard to C99 at least (and preferably C11). If your compiler is very ancient (previous century) you'll need to upgrade it too!

Comment: My prof wants us to code c in a text editor using C89 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why you have to read all bytes one by one to count them? It is much easier to do `fseek( fp, 0, 2 )` to jump at end of file and get current position (file length) with `ftell( fp )`.

Comment: You should specify `SEEK_END` instead of `2` to make what is being done clearer.

Comment: Yes, SEEK_END is the named definition.

Comment: In the end seeking made the loop run. I remember the professor talking about this a few weeks back but didn't think to apply it here. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you write to the file and then call your method on the same file handle, the file handle is already at the end of the file so it will see EOF immediately. We would need to see more of the code to be sure I think.

So, you could rewind the file handle at the start of your function.

Or you could just call ftell to find out your offset in the file, which is the same as the number of bytes written if you truncate, write and do not rewind.

Comment: Here is the method which adds data to a file. Beware it was written in one sitting at 4 am.
http://puu.sh/g76hX/40ae456344.txt

Answer (score 0):

You are opening with the mode `w+` which will truncate the file. From the fopen man page:

> w+        Open for reading and writing.  The file is created if it does not exist, otherwise it is truncated.  The stream is positioned at the beginning of the file.

You will want to open it with `rb+` instead of `wb+` if you are reading from a file and still want to write to it. If you have already written to it and want to read what was written, you will need to seek to the start of the file pointer.

```
// Both of these seek to the start
rewind(fp);
fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_SET);
```

Comment: Flow should be like this:
./a (filename)
"ok"
add Homer Simpson 100
"ok"
add Marge Simpson 99
"ok"
display 2
Simpson, Marge: 99;


Basically the program is a loop until the user sends a null (crtl+d). 
If a file is passed in as a param and the file already exists it is overwritten. Otherwise it is created.

Answer (score 0):

If the file is not open, you could use:

```
off_t getFileSize(const char *filepath) {
   struct stat fileStat;
   stat(filepath, &fileStat);
   return(fileStat.st_size);
}
```

If the file is open:

```
off_t getFileSize(int fd) {
   struct stat fileStat;
   fstat(fd, &fileStat);
   return(fileStat.st_size);
}
```